# RPi + eth-usb adapter + isc-dhcp-server

Tags: dhcp

RPI3, Raspbian, dhcp server (isc-dhcp-server)

I have a device connected to RPi3 directly through usb-ethernet adapter (I need 2 ethernet ports: 1 eth by RPi3 and 1 by usb-eth adapter)

But I cant see my device! Device is working 100% (checked).
Isc-dhcp-server giving adresses normally, I connected macbook to RPI3 and RPI3 give me correct address between range in my config.

Okay, configs and other info:

**ip l**:

```
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:36:31:99 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**nano /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf**:

```
ddns-update-style none;
    authoritative;
    subnet 192.168.5.0 netmask 255.255.255.240 {
      range 192.168.5.11 192.168.5.12;
      option routers 192.168.5.14;
      default-lease-time 31536000;
      max-lease-time 31536000;
    }
```

**nano /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server**:

```
INTERFACESv4="eth1"
```

**nano /etc/network/interfaces**

```
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.5.10
netmask 255.255.255.240
gateway 192.168.5.8
auto eth1
```

**iptables-save**

```
empty
```

**arp-scan --interface=eth1 --localnet**

```
Interface: eth1, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.9 with 16 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)

0 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.9: 16 hosts scanned in 2.891 seconds (5.53 hosts/sec). 0 responded
```

**root@raspberrypi:/var/log# systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service**

```
● isc-dhcp-server.service - LSB: DHCP server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-08-11 13:02:56 UTC; 58min ago
  Process: 1595 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1608 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/isc-dhcp-server.service
           └─1621 /usr/sbin/dhcpd -4 -q -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf eth1

Aug 11 13:56:44 raspberrypi dhcpd[1621]: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:e0:4c:36:31:99 (raspberrypi) via eth1
Aug 11 13:56:45 raspberrypi dhcpd[1621]: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.5.11 to 00:e0:4c:36:31:99 (raspberrypi) via eth1
Aug 11 13:57:48 raspberrypi dhcpd[1621]: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:e0:4c:36:31:99 (raspberrypi) via eth1
Aug 11 13:57:50 raspberrypi dhcpd[1621]: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.5.11 to 00:e0:4c:36:31:99 (raspberrypi) via eth1
Aug 11 13:58:52 raspberrypi dhcpd[1621]: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:e0:4c:36:31:99 (raspberrypi) via eth1
Aug 11 13:58:53 raspberrypi dhcpd[1621]: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.5.11 to 00:e0:4c:36:31:99 (raspberrypi) via eth1
Aug 11 13:59:57 raspberrypi dhcpd[1621]: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:e0:4c:36:31:99 (raspberrypi) via eth1
Aug 11 13:59:58 raspberrypi dhcpd[1621]: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.5.11 to 00:e0:4c:36:31:99 (raspberrypi) via eth1
Aug 11 14:01:01 raspberrypi dhcpd[1621]: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:e0:4c:36:31:99 (raspberrypi) via eth1
Aug 11 14:01:02 raspberrypi dhcpd[1621]: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.5.11 to 00:e0:4c:36:31:99 (raspberrypi) via eth1
```

**nano /var/log/syslog**

```
Aug 11 13:45:01 raspberrypi dhcpd[1621]: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:e0:4c:36:31:99 (raspberrypi) via eth1
Aug 11 13:45:02 raspberrypi dhcpd[1621]: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.5.11 to 00:e0:4c:36:31:99 (raspberrypi) via eth1
Aug 11 13:46:05 raspberrypi dhcpd[1621]: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:e0:4c:36:31:99 (raspberrypi) via eth1
Aug 11 13:46:05 raspberrypi rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 17' suspended, next retry is Fri Aug 11 13:47:35 2017 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Aug 11 13:46:06 raspberrypi dhcpd[1621]: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.5.11 to 00:e0:4c:36:31:99 (raspberrypi) via eth1
Aug 11 13:47:10 raspberrypi dhcpd[1621]: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:e0:4c:36:31:99 (raspberrypi) via eth1
Aug 11 13:47:11 raspberrypi dhcpd[1621]: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.5.11 to 00:e0:4c:36:31:99 (raspberrypi) via eth1
```

Why I cant see my device? Whats the problem with dhcp? 
Also I cant setup my device, because it closed for changing code in it.
Does anybody knows?
Thanks